# Defining a Constraint for a Component and Enforcing it in Openmdao

Tags: openmdao

I am new to openmdao and am trying to solve a problem with 2 disciplines (defined as explicit components). The first component gets a number of input values and create a number of outputs which are passed to the second component so these two components are connected. Now, I want to set a constraint on the second component to ensure that one of the output values of this component is bounded between -1 and 1 (the output value is the cosine of an angel calculated based on some design variables).

In the file related to the second component, I've added a function for the the constraint however during the calculations the constraint is not enforced. I've used

```
def add_constraint(self, outputs):
    self.add_constraint(outputs['cosGamma'], lower = -1, upper = 1)
```

In another attempt, I defined this constraint on the system level. In details, first a subsytem defining the constraint function was added to the system using `self.add_subsystem` which promotes `gGamma` as an output. This function calculates the cosine of an angel (Gamma) based on the system level variables. Then `problem.model.add_constraint('gGamma', lower = -1, upper= 1)` was used to put constraint on gGamma. Yet, the constraint is not enforced again.

I am wondering how this constraint can be enforced in this scenario.

Comment: Hi there, we'll need more information to help understand and solve your problem. Can you please share a run script where you are running this model? Constraints are only enforced when using an optimizer by calling `run_driver()`, not when you just call `run_model().

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, first I use 'problem.setup()' then I set up initial values using the 'problem.set_val()' . After that, I use 'problem.check_config()' and 'problem.run_driver()'.

Comment: If you haven't yet, could you please go through the `Adding constraints` doc? https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/adding_desvars_cons_objs/adding_constraint.html

Also, the optimizer may query the design space in a way that the constraint is not satisfied. The constraints are not guaranteed to be satisfied during the optimization.